# React Native Redux - redirect after login

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a react native app. When user logs in, I have set isLoggedIn = true in reducer.

Login is done by this action: this.props.login(user)

If login is successful, I want to redirect user to home page. I could do it in getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method. Is that correct/recommended approach?

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: Yes. Main query is that where should I be writing the navigation code?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you navigate in a middleware action, such as [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

You can do this by creating a [`NavigationService`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html), which allows you to navigate without the navigation prop, which you can then import and use wherever you define your actions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be anti-pattern to navigate in action? I would obviously not do in reducer.

Comment: Could you explain what makes it an anti-pattern? This is how I've been approaching it and I'm wondering what you think the cons would be. I use `redux-thunk` for an async action, then if the login succeeds, I save the user's information in the redux store and navigate, but if it fails, then I don't navigate and I save an error message in the store, which the login page receives as a prop through `connect` and display it. Invoking an `Alert` rather than saving an error message could work as well.

Comment: anti pattern meaning something which is not recommended by redux. Correct me if I am wrong - I was under impression that we should not write any business logic etc. in redux. It should be kept as simple as possible.

Comment: Ah ok. It's true that base redux should be kept simple. However, with redux middleware, like `redux-thunk`, you can dispatch actions with business logic that will then dispatch standard redux actions that change the store. This article can tell you more about business logic in redux: https://medium.com/@jeffbski/where-do-i-put-my-business-logic-in-a-react-redux-application-9253ef91ce1